# How to switch between HTML formats depending on the type of content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, json

I'm looking for a solution how to switch between multiple html formats depending on the type of content that is stored in my JSON.

I am now using AJAX and JSON to fill in the HTML format: `format-text.html`.

```
      $.ajax({
                    url: 'api/datacontent.json',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(data) {
        
                        root.dataArr = data;
                        root.objectArr = root.dataArr.content;
                        root.timeEvent;     
                        root.triggeredId = -1; 
       
        
                        $.get('directives/format-text.html', function(response){
                            console.log('succes');
                        })
                        
                        .done(function (response) {
                              // Here I fill in the blanks with a for loop
                        }

                        .fail(function (response) {
                             console.dir(response); 
                        });
}
```

JSON:

```
{
        "title":    "Data content",
        "content":  [
            {
                "type" :        "youtube",
                "timeTrigger":  5,
                "title":        "Youtube",
                "subtitle":     "YouTube Channel",
                "picture" :     "images/content/london.jpg",
                "text":         "Visit their YouTube channel here.",
            },{
                "type" :        "location",
                "timeTrigger":  25,
                "title":        "London",
                "google":       "https://www.google.nl/maps/place/Londen,+Verenigd+Koninkrijk/@51.5340878,-0.0978221,12z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x47d8a00baf21de75:0x52963a5addd52a99"
            },{
                "type":         "text",
                "timeTrigger":  34,
                "title":        "Sherlock Holmes",
                "subtitle":     "Detective",
                "picture" :     "images/content/sherlockholmes.jpg",
                "text":         "Sherlock Holmes is a fictional detective created by British author Sir Arthur Conan Doyle. Holmes is known for his astute logical reasoning, his ability to adopt almost any disguise, and his use of forensic science to solve difficult cases.",
                "readmore":     "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherlock_Holmes"
            }
```

As you can see I use the format-text.html to fill in the content. But my JSON file consists of multiple types of content, like location, text and an external link, with for each type a different CSS style.
How can I switch between those HTML contents and fill in the right block of content?

Comment: Can you provide your HTML expected output too pls

Comment: What do you exactly mean. The HTML markups where I want to switch between, or how I append the content to the blocks?

Answer (score 1):

It is a little chaotic, you didn't told us how you want to category these datatypes in the view.

Anyway if the API is handling everything in a single list, than you could categorise the results in a new array.

```
var formattedArr = {
  'videos' : [],
  'locations' : [],
  'texts' : []
};

for( var i =0; i <= dataContent.content.length; i++ ) {
  switch( dataContent.content[i].type ) {
    case 'youtube' : formatedArr.videos.push( dataContent.content[i] ); break;
    case 'location' :formatedArr.locations.push( dataContent.content[i] ); break;
    case 'text' : formatedArr.texts.push( dataContent.content[i] );
  }
}
```

Then you can easily loop through the types. Of course it would be better if the API would give you your desired format.

Comment: My apologize for that. In my JSON I have the variable "type" where I define what kind of content it contains. So in the for loop it should check which content type it is and depending on that get the right markup file and fill it in... How should I do that in your example?

Comment: Okay, this is will need more than one answer. Your application's architecture should follow: 1. load your data json 2. load your external templates 3. loop through your json and by the above code switch cases. Within it call a function that loads stuff into your template. Then you can append the snippets to the desired tags.

Comment: Can you create a snippet of how this should look likes, in the very basic setup?

Comment: Unfortunately a snippet wouldn't suffice; please read this resource:
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/best-practices-when-working-with-javascript-templates--net-28364

Then you could ask your remaining questions separately.